# Facebook Connect require login for some links

Tags: facebook

Is there any fb tag i can use to wrap around my html anchor tag so that if the user isn't logged in, they will get prompted to login before getting access to the link?

I'm using python/django in backend.

Thanks,
David

Comment: What is this, iframe fb app? Or standalone site?

Comment: at this point it has nothing to do with FB, just like any authorized access process, if you have a valid session proceed, otherwise prompt

Answer (score 0):

You simply need an if statement to check whether a facebook session exist or not. If not redirect them to the login page.

-Roozbeh

Answer (score 0):

First I think you must create a Facebook App.

Second: if you are programming in PHP, you should use the PHP SDK.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Third: Use **getUser** method:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/

I'm almost sure that getUser will return 0 if the user has not accepted your app, so IMO it's **not the best method to find the user connection status on Facebook**.

Also, **getLoginStatusUrl** could help, with this function you could make redirections *based on the user status on Facebook*, and think of a mechanism to show or not the contents based on parameters and session variables (it's an idea).

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginStatusUrl/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the JavaScript API you'll want to use FB.getLoginStatus to wrap around the anchor tag. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Example from that page:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and connected to your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    //but not connected to the app
  } else {
    // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

Note: I would simply make this call up front and set my own JS variable boolean on the response so I didn't have to use the FB API call again. Then wrap any dependent code with a simple JS boolean test.